# Calling the UI Api from a community with a custom domain name - getting sun.validator exception

Tags: rest-api, security, custom-domain

**Context**: we're using the UI api to get some Record Type dependent picklist values back.  This is happening in a community context.

In the lower environments (dev, QA) this works without issue.  The remote site settings seem to be fine and we get the values back.

**Problem**: In production, which uses a custom domain name for the community, we're running into trouble and getting this error when the call is made:

```
System.HttpRequest retrying request in response to handshake failure: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

From what I'm seeing, the url of the REST request is formed using the custom domain name in the prod environment, but uses the normal salesforce community domain name in the lower environments.  The remote site settings appear to be similarly configured.

It does appear we have a self-signed certificate in place that doesn't expire until 2020, but I'm wondering if there needs to be some other change to accomodate the custom domain name?

edit: this is calling Salesforce UI API from a Sales Cloud hosted domain.  Not a batch process calling an outbound api.

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate @PranayJaiswal.. this deals with calling Salesforce UI API from a custom domain serving a Salesforce Community implementation.

Comment: It's http callout in the end and the error exactly match? The certificate you added to custom domain doesn't seem to configured properly

Comment: I suspect that's correct.  Unfortunately, I didn't add it and don't have control over it.  Trying to advise the people with power on how to proceed. From what I can tell, RapidSSL is an intermediate CA before digicert.  I'm doing some research on certificate chains to see if that clarifies anything.